# Finite Difference Method MATLAB Program

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I am a beginner to MATLAB.
I am trying to create a MATLAB program for the finite difference which is to calculate potential in a grid.
I have to include a condition such that the iterations stop once the difference between the last two iterations of potential for all nodes is less than 0.001.
Here v(i,j) represents the potential.

I was thinking of a IF loop, but did not know how to end it/exit it.
Say like v(i,j) - v(i-1,j-1) = 0.001.

```
clc
clear all 
close all

v1 =0;  
v3 = 139;
v2 = 0;
v4 = 0;

ni = 200; % no. of iterations
nx = 6;
ny = 5;

v = zeros(nx,ny);

for i =2:nx-1
   v(i,1) = v1;
   v(i,ny) = v3;

end
for j=2:ny-1
  v(1,j) = v4;
  v(nx,j) = v2;

end
   v(1,1) = 0.5*(v1 + v4)
   v(nx,1)  = 0.5 * (v1 +v2)
   v(1,ny) = 0.5*(v3 + v4)
   v(nx,ny) = 0.5* (v2+v3)

for k = 1:ni
  for i =2:nx-1
    for j = 2:ny-1
        v(i,j) = 0.25*(v(i+1,j)+v(i-1,j) +v(i,j+1)+v(i,j-1));
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

A classical approach is the following. Always store the previous solution along with the new one. Then use a while loop that continues as long as the criterion is not fulfilled. For example one can continue as long as

$$\max|v -v_{\text{old}}|>0.001 $$

also known as the infinity norm, i.e. $\|v-v_{\text{old}}\|_{\infty}>0.001$.

```
v_old = zeros(size(v));
k = 0;
NormDiff = 1; % inititialize some norm value to enter loop.
while k<max_iter && NormDiff>0.001
   --- update iteration on v here ---
   k = k + 1; % Update iteration number.
   NormDiff = norm(v-v_old,'Inf'); % Calculate the norm difference.
   v_old = v; % Store the new iteration as the old one.
end
```

Comment: Thanks sir.,but could you please explain me how to use this in the program.

Comment: I already gave you the MATLAB code. The while loop should be in the place where you iterated $k$.

Comment: And at the line where I wrote "udate iteration on v here" you should have the double for-loop where you iterate $i$ and $j$. And `max_iter` is `ni` in your code.

Comment: The following errors I am getting:,                                                                                               Error using norm
The only matrix norms available are 1, 2, inf, and 'fro'.

Error in kjhgiug (line 35)
while k<ni && norm(v-v_old,'infinity')>0.001

Comment: You're right, it should be `inf` or `Inf`, not `infinity`.

Comment: Yes,'inf' worked.But the results were not as expected.Before with the for loops(i.e without the 0.001 condition) , I was getting a matrix of size(v) with values in all entries filled.But with the while loop there was only two columns filled with values and others zero.One of them with v3 =139 and the other beside one with calculated values and then the program terminated.

Comment: It should work now. However, you should really learn to how to debug a program in MATLAB. I did not actually write the code and test it, I just wrote it as an answer using syntax from memory. Since I don't didn't test the code it was quite likely that there were some small bugs. You need to learn to how fix small bugs as these, otherwise it is going to be impossible for you to actually make something on your own. For example the error message you wrote with the 'infinity' clearly states what the problem is.

Comment: Hello again,for the 0.001 condition.If I say the difference between the sum of all elements of a new matrix with the sum of all elements of previous is greater than (0.001*order of matrix) then terminate else keep running.will this help ? This loop can be started say by ni = 27, I.e to avoid unnecessary termination.